# JSONB or Array of Ints

Tags: arrays, postgresql, database-design, jsonb

I have a column in my database where I would like to store something called `external_ids`.

So my table kinda looks like

```
id (int, pk..)
name (text...)
description (text...)
external_ids (int[])
```

I know that my use case will be to store multiple numbers in that row and it will never need to be anything beyond that.

Given that requirement, is there a reason to make that type a JSONB, or will I get more benefit keeping it an array?

Comment: Are these numbers used as relational data or are they just dumb data? With an `ARRAY` column you can be sure it's an array. With `JSONB` it could be any number of things, many of which make no sense.

Comment: Its just dumb data.

Comment: Using `ARRAY` is probably fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON offers more flexibility than an array. In this case where the data will always be a series of integer IDs, it makes no sense to use JSON. Just stick to an array.

Comment: As a bonus, Postgres `ARRAY` types have concrete Postgres types within. JSON can get a bit wild and unruly.